# Max number of namespaces that can be used in one Android XML

Tags: android, xml, namespaces

I need to know how many custom namespaces can we use in one Android XML

here I am using two custom components

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:parallax="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.example.abc.components.ParallaxImageView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    parallax:tiltSensitivity="2.5" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent_white" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_registration_hi_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="@string/activity_registration_hi"
        android:textSize="@dimen/activity_title_text" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/activity_registration_hi_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="@string/activity_registration_welcome_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/activity_large_text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activity_registration_sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/signin_button_selector"
        android:text="@string/activity_registration_google_plus" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/activity_registration_sign_in_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_reduced"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_left_devider" />

    <com.example.abc.components.FloatLabelEditText
        android:id="@+id/activity_change_password_old_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:hint="@string/activity_change_password_old_password_hint"
        app:textColor="@color/white"
        app:textColorHintFocused="@color/red"
        app:textColorHintUnFocused="@color/grey"
        app:textHintColor="@color/faded_white"
        app:textSize="@dimen/button_textSize" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

At FloatLabelEditText component it gives

> unbound prefix error

and if I change the namespace from 'parallax' to 'app' than ParallaxImageView gives error.

I searched everywhere tried many things but canot resolve this.
Please some one tell me. **Can we use more than one Custom Components in one XML ??**

I might be wrong but please, need help!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the namespace `app:` in the attributes on the `com.example.abc.components.FloatLabelEditText` element, and the namespace `parallax` on the `com.example.abc.components.ParallaxImageView` element, but only one namespace is defined (besides android). You need to add `xmlns:app="*"` to the `RelativeLayout` element, or change the `app:` namespaces to `parallax:` depending on where the attributes are coming from.

Comment: Off-course I am totally aware of that. Since I am using two custom views **ParallaxImageView** and the other one **FloatLabelEditText**.  
  
So I need to declare two namespaces that XML is not accepting!  
  
I already tried what you are saying, like either use **app** or **parallax** as the namespace while declaring xml attributes of the components. In that case all the component attributes show error.  
eg.  
"error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value '@string/
 activity_change_password_old_password_hint')."  
  
**like this**

Comment: **UPDATE**  

It was my mistake. Yeah its right, you can have any number of Namespaces in an xml. but its a good practice to put them in one package if they are all custom components.